# Как реализвать ссылку на значение объекта в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная d (библиотека jQUERY):

```
$(function() {


        var d = [[ссылка на значение объекта VarValue,ссылка на значение объекта Time_ms],[]];

        // first correct the timestamps - they are recorded as the daily
        // midnights in UTC+0100, but Flot always displays dates in UTC
        // so we have to add one hour to hit the midnights in the plot

        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
            d[i][0] += 60 * 60 * 1000;
        }
```

Есть функция, которая выводит необходимые элементы массива:

```
    function completeFn({data}) { data.forEach(function(row, index) {
    data[index] = [+row.VarValue, +row.Time_ms];
  console.log('Элемент массива значение ['+index+'] = '+row.VarValue);
  console.log('Элемент массива время ['+index+'] = '+row.Time_ms);

    });
}
```

Выводится так (взято из консоли)

```
Элемент массива значение [0] = 0 
Элемент массива время [0] = 43614696006,875 
Элемент массива значение [1] = 0 
Элемент массива время [1] = 43614696018,6111 
Элемент массива значение [2] = 0 
Элемент массива время [2] = 43614696030,3356 
Элемент массива значение [3] = 0 
Элемент массива время [3] = 43614696042,0602 
Элемент массива значение [4] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [4] = 43614696044,1782 
Элемент массива значение [5] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [5] = 43614696053,7963 
Элемент массива значение [6] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [6] = 43614696065,544 
Элемент массива значение [7] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [7] = 43614696077,2917 
Элемент массива значение [8] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [8] = 43614696089,0509 
Элемент массива значение [9] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [9] = 43614696100,8102 
Элемент массива значение [10] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [10] = 43614696112,5579 
Элемент массива значение [11] = 0,1692708 
Элемент массива время [11] = 43614696124,3171
```

Необходимо сделать ссылку на значения объекта массива

```
var d = [[Элемент массива значение [0] = 0,Элемент массива время [0] = 43614696006,875], [Элемент массива значение [1] = 0,Элемент массива время [1] = 43614696018,6111]]
```

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: А что такое "переменная в HTML" ?) Может её значение позже добавляется в HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
function completeFn({data}) { data.forEach(function(row, index) {
    d[index] = [+row.VarValue + (60 * 60 * 1000), +row.Time_ms];
    // (60 * 60 * 1000) - при необходимости. Не ясно, у вас оно происходит до или после
  });
}
```